# I receive an error while migrating my models to a database

Tags: django, django-migrations

I get such an error while migrating to a database:

```
 return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "user_auth_customer" 
 referencing "user_auth_profile"
```

I have checked Foreign_Keys of my models and they look good.

I have no idea why I receive that error :(

Please, help me out here.

`class Customer(AbstractUser):`

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
objects = UserManager()

id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,  unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

profile = models.OneToOneField("Profile", related_name="user_profile",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', null=True,  blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(validators=[validators.EmailValidator()],
                          unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

@staticmethod
def get_customer_by_email(email):
    try:
        return Customer.objects.get(email=email)
    except:
        return False

def isExists(self):
    if Customer.objects.filter(email=self.email):
        return True

    return False

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Customer'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Customers'
```

`class Profile(models.Model):`

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', null=True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True, unique=True, validators=[validators.EmailValidator()])
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
# Add a photo field
owner = models.OneToOneField(Customer, related_name='profile_owner',
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True,
                            validators=[UnicodeUsernameValidator()])
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Profile'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
```

if you need any else details, I can provide you with those in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have both ways `OneToOneField`. Choose one way.

If you delete `Customer`'s `profile` field, then still you will have possibility to call relation with:

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=1)
customer.profile   # that will call Customer's related Profile object
```

Assuming, that you will change `related_name='profile_owner'` to simpler `related_name='profile'`.

Read more about [OneToOneRelationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).